# Variable value not being passed into another class

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to let the user to choose which option is in their menu, and setting the variables based on the option that the customer choose, but when I go to another class and retrieve it, there is no value being passed.

Here is my `alacarte` class

```
public class Alacarte {
    public void alacarte(){
        Checkout c = new Checkout();
        System.out.println("Please select a meal");
        System.out.println("\n1. Fried Chicken........9.90");
        System.out.println("2. McChicken..........5.90");
        System.out.println("3. Spicy Chicken McDeluxe......12.90");
        System.out.println("\nOption:");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = s.nextInt();
        switch(option){
            case 1:
            this.order = "Fried Chicken";
            this.price = 9.90;
            c.receipt();
        
            case 2:
            this.order = "McChicken";
            this.price = 5.90;

            
            case 3:
            this.order = "Spicy Chicken McDeluxe";
            this.price = 12.90;
             
        }
    }
    private String order;
    private double price;
    public double getPrice(){
        return this.price;
    }
    public String getOrder(){
        return this.order;
    }

}
```

Here is my `checkout` class

```
public class Checkout {
     public void receipt(){
         Alacarte as = new Alacarte();
         System.out.println("Thank you for your order");
         System.out.println("Your order is: " + as.getOrder());
         System.out.println("The price is: " + as.getPrice());
         System.out.println("\nThank you for ordering with us!");
     }
}
```

Here is my `output`

```
Thank you for your order
Your order is: null
The price is: 0.0

Thank you for ordering with us!
```

Comment: Your `Alacarte` object is calling `receipt` which is instantiating another `Alacart` - I think you pass `reciept` the values you already have.

Comment: May I know how do I solve this issue @ScaryWombat

Comment: Watch out! Your `case` blocks of your `switch` statement are *falling through* the next ones. This may not be what you want.

Comment: @MCEmperor how do i prevent this issue

Comment: @ScaryWombat also, when i rerun my program, my output stacks, do i change my switch case statement or do I need to clear my get set methods?

My output is as such:-

`Thank you for your order
Your order is: Fried Chicken
The price is: 9.9

Thank you for ordering with us!
Thank you for your order
Your order is: McChicken
The price is: 5.9

Thank you for ordering with us!
Thank you for your order
Your order is: Spicy Chicken McDeluxe
The price is: 12.9`

Comment: You need to put in `break` statements - read up on switch statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the information here

```
        this.order = "Fried Chicken";
        this.price = 9.90;
        c.receipt();
```

so change `receipt` so that it has parameters

```
        this.order = "Fried Chicken";
        this.price = 9.90;
        c.receipt(this.order, this.price);
```

Change the implementation

```
public void receipt(String order, float price){
     System.out.println("Thank you for your order");
     System.out.println("Your order is: " + order);
     System.out.println("The price is: " + price);
     System.out.println("\nThank you for ordering with us!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a new instance of Alacarte in you receipt method which does not know anything about the user input. One way to do this is to pass the data to the receipt method as parameters.

```
c.receipt(this.order, this.price);
```

And in Checkout:

```
public void receipt(String order, float price) {
    System.out.println("Thank you for your order");
    System.out.println("Your order is: " + order);
    System.out.println("The price is: " + price);
    System.out.println("\nThank you for ordering with us!");
}
```

NB! Add break statement at the end of your switch cases and default at the end.